# Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit ERC721: transfer of token that is not own"

Tags: solidity

I'm getting ERC721 transfer of token that is not own.
any help, please?

Unhandled Rejection (Error): cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted: ERC721: transfer of token that is not own","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000294552433732313a207472616e73666572206f6620746f6b656e2074686174206973206e6f74206f776e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: ERC721: transfer of token that is not own"}}}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xFeB43BA464258c453D7aA678210fD49zxnFRgfBN","to":"0x81b6BfD84f5FBa7c737382Bd535875DDF4bFD443","value":

Creat ERC721 Token:

```
function createToken(string memory _tokenURI) public returns (uint) {
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

    _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI);
    setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
    return newItemId;}
```

Put on Sale and transfer:

```
 function createSale( address nftContract,
uint256 itemId
) public payable nonReentrant {
uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
require(msg.value == price, "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, tokenId);
idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
_itemsSold.increment();
payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice); }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having same error and I came up with 2 solutions:

1. In your `hardhat.config.js`, add manual gas limit in networks:

   ```
   your network: {
       url: `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}`,
       accounts: [privateKey],
       gas: 2100000,
       gasPrice: 8000000000,
   }
   ```
2. In your `index.js` file, instead of mainnet in `Web3Modal`, use your network:

   ```
   const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
       network: "your network name",
       cacheProvider: true,
   })
   ```